# Spring data rest Hateoas - How to deal with different uris for the same entity

Tags: rest, repository, spring-hateoas

I have Item entities exposed via the user repository in the form of:

> http://localhost:8080/api/users/0/items

and exposed via the item repository as:

> http://localhost:8080/api/items

Only the later one accepts a post and the first one does not support post action.

If a client gets

> http://localhost:8080/api/users/0/items/1

and tries to update the item it gets back a:

```
"status": 405,
"error": "Method Not Allowed",
```

Updating via following url works fine:

> http://localhost:8080/api/items/1

Is there a way and does it make sense to allow updates on both repositories or is there a way to tell the client what url it should use for a post action in a restful way?

Comment: DO you use Spring Data REST? If so then `http://localhost:8080/api/users/0/items` is an association resource, not a collection resource.

Comment: Yes I use SDR with Neo4j. And it's new to me. What if it is an association resource? Is it not allowed to post new resources via it? If so, how does a consumer know what url to post to to create a new associated resource?

Comment: The way you have designed your repositories `items` and `users` are independent from each other. You only post to their respective collection URI to create a new resource. If you want to establish a connection between the two you can post e.g. the URI(!) `http://localhost:8080/api/items/1` to the association resource `http://localhost:8080/api/users/0/items`. That would associate the user 0 with the item 1.

Comment: Ok this is interesting. But I meant more like a client who has retrieved a user from `http://localhost:8080/api/users/0` and a list of associated items from `http://localhost:8080/api/users/0/items` through the `items` link of the user. How does it know where the items repository is to create a new item? The whole point of hateoas is that the client doesn't have to know about the web addresses am I wrong? So it would have to check a self link on an Item, but what if the associated items list is yet empty?

Comment: _The whole point of hateoas is that the client doesn't have to know about the web addresses_ - I wouldn't use those exact words, but I think you mean the right thing. And that's the beauty of HATEOS: You can give a client information of what to do next or where to look things up by simply adding links to a resource (response). So you could add a link with the relation `itemsRepository` to a `user` response. I'm not advocating this idea, but it's an option.

Comment: In general a client **using** (not just browsing!) your API has to have **some** a priori knowledge about it. It has to know what a user is, what an item is etc.  So it would also have to know that there is an endpoint for items. It can get the address for that endpoint by calling `http://localhost:8080/api/` and retrieving the link for `items`. So while HATEOAS doesn't require knowing addresses in advance it still requires a client to have some knowledge in order to sensibly use the API.

Comment: A browsing and a using client, ok. Still, should the knowledge of `/api/items/` be a priori to a client using the `/api/users/0/items`? Can it not be returned in the response to `get /api/users/0/items`? I know it's included in the`/api/` response but it's not obvious that `/api/items/` and `/api/users/0/items` are related. I can't think of a way to capture that relation programatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`users`and `items` have their own repositories. That means that an `item` is not tied to a specific `user` - it can belong to no, any or many `users`, depending on your constraints. It also means that the `user` repository does not control the lifecycle of `items`. In other words posting an `item` to any URL starting with `/api/users` is out of scope.

`/api/users/0/items` is a so called association resource. It is used to establish a relation between a `user`and an `item`. It's done by posting the URI of an `item` to this URL. But the item has to exist.

The resulting question was how should the client know? You correctly noted that the point of HATEOAS is that the client doesn't have to know links or, even worse, has to create them by hand. Please, note that there's a huge difference between not knowing the links and not knowing the API. Not knowing `/api/items` and not knowing that there is an item repository is not the same. Also e.g. without knowing what a `user` is - semantically - it doesn't make sense to use the API.

Are there alternatives? Not really. You could implement a controller handling requests to `/api/users/0/items`. But that's a lot of work for every association resource. You could add the link of the item repository to every `user` via a [ResourceProcessor](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/wiki/Customizing-the-JSON-output). But that might be confusing because you would then have a link `items` and one `itemRepository` or `addItems`.

Comment: How about posting an item to `api/items` with a user uri assigned to the user associated field of item. It seems to work, whats wrong with it?

Comment: I mean instead of posting a new item and then posting the association separately.

Comment: @aycanadal You didn't mention that the relation is bidirectional. But, of course, posting a resource including association URIs is a good approach :)